# pointer to a pointer in a struct using apr_shm library

Tags: c++, c, apache, pointers, struct

I got the apache module code using apr shared library [here](http://www.codemass.com/mod_shm_counter/).

And I modified to shared data struct add some field that has pointer to a pointer, and so on like this..

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char *str;
    double **dpp;
    STRU1 **str;
} shm_data;

/* The per-server configuration */
typedef struct {
    char *shmcounterfile;
    char *shmcounterlockfile;
    apr_global_mutex_t *mutex; /* the cross-thread/cross-process mutex */
    apr_shm_t *data_shm;   /* the APR shared segment object */
    shm_data *data;  /* the per-process address of the segment */
} shm_data_scfg_t;

...

/* parent httpd init code => ap_hook_post_config */
scfg = (shm_data_scfg_t*)ap_get_module_config(s->module_config, &shm_module);

apr_shm_create(&scfg->data_shm, sizeof(*scfg->data),
                            scfg->shmcounterfile, pconf);
/* The pointer to the shm_data structure is only valid
 * in the current process, since in another process it may
 * not be mapped in the same address-space. This is especially
 * likely on Windows or when accessing the segment from an
 * external process. */
scfg->data = (shm_data*)apr_shm_baseaddr_get(scfg->data_shm);

/* Clear all the data in the structure. */
memset(scfg->data, 0, sizeof(*scfg->data));

scfg->data->a = 1;
scfg->data->b = 2;
scfg->data->str = "test";

scfg->data->dpp = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
    scfg->data->dpp[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 10);
    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {   
        scfg->data->dpp[i][l] = l;
    }   
}
...
```

And it works fine. Child processes can access the values of 'dpp' or 'str' pointed are same as it is.

As far as i know malloc'd allocated private memory in a process(parent httpd) that can't read from other process. (child httpd)

How does this work? Any help appreciated.

Comment: "*...  memory ....can't access each other.*" Please what do you want to express?

Comment: Also is this about C or C++? I'd say C because you seem to be using APR, right?

Comment: i mean, value of the pointer is only be valid in the current  process. sorry. i'm poor in english.  and this compiled in g++ using apr.

Comment: Which pointer? And it is not obvious from your question, that you are dealing with more than one process.

Comment: the double pointer 'dpp' in shared struct(shm_data) and also other pointer vars in that. I don't know.. maybe the reason for it worked is apr_shm_create function implement with shm_open and mmap..instead of shmget..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that this code may *appear* to work if you are using an Apache MPM such as [`worker`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) which uses threads heavily, since all of the threads will share an address space with each other, as well as with their parent process. However, it will not work under heavy load (as Apache will start to use different processes for each set of threads), or at all under the [`prefork`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html) mpm.

If you want to store data in shared memory, **all of the data** must be stored in shared memory (i.e, you cannot use `malloc()` for any of it), and you cannot use pointers within that memory (since they will become invalid if the shm region is mapped to a different location).

Comment: thanks. but i use prefork mpm.. dynamically allocated pointer var('dpp') in shared struct still visible to every other process.